# How to handle onClick events for array objects in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add an `onClick` event handler to objects in an array where the class of a clicked object is changed, but instead of only changing one element's class, it changes the classes of all the elements.

How can I get the function to work on only one `section` element at a time?

```
class Tiles extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            clicked: false,
            content : []
        };
    this.onClicked = this.onClicked.bind(this);

componentDidMount() {
    let url = '';
    let request = new Request(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
    });
    fetch(request)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({
            content : data
        })
    } );

}

onClicked() {
    this.setState({
        clicked: !this.state.clicked
        });
}

render() {
    let tileClass = 'tile-content';
    if (this.state.clicked) {
        tileClass = tileClass + ' active'
    }
    return (
    <div className = 'main-content'>
    {this.state.pages.map((item) => 
        <section key = {item.id} className = {tileClass} onClick = {this.onClicked}>
        <h4>{item.description}</h4>
        </section>)}
        <br />
    </div>
    )
 }

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return (
        <div>
            <Tiles />
        </div>
       )
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(
     <App />,
    document.getElementById('content-app'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have onClicked() define in your 'main-content' class.  So that's where it fires.

```
constructor(props) {
    // super, etc., code
    this.onClicked = this.onClicked.bind(this);    // Remove this line.
}
```

Remove that part.

You can keep the `onClicked()` function where it is.  Your call in render() is incorrect, though: `onClick = {this.onClicked}>`.  That accesses the onClicked *ATTRIBUTE*, not the onClicked *FUNCTION*, it should be this.onClicked().

Let me cleanup your call in `render()` a little bit:

```
render() {
  let tileClass = 'tile-content';
  return (
    <div className = 'main-content'>
          // some stuff
          <section
               key={item.id}
               className={tileClass}
               onClick={() => this.onClicked()}        // Don't call bind here.
          >
            <h4>{item.description}</h4>
          </section>
          // some other stuff
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but even after trying your way the same thing happens. All the `section` elements get updated at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening for you, because you are assigning active class to all sections once user clicked on one of them. You need somehow to remember where user clicked. So I suggest you to use array, where you will store indexes of all clicked sections. In this case your state.clicked is an array now.

```
onClicked(number) {
  let clicked = Object.assign([], this.state.clicked);
  let index = clicked.indexOf(number);
  if(index !== -1) clicked.splice(index, 1);
  else clicked.push(number)
  this.setState({
    clicked: clicked
  });
}

render() {
  let tileClass = 'tile-content';
  return (
    <div className = 'main-content'>
      {this.state.pages.map((item, i) => { 
        let tileClass = 'tile-content';
        if(this.state.clicked.includes(i)) tile-content += ' active';
        return (
          <section key = {item.id} className = {tileClass} onClick = {this.onClicked.bind(this, i)}>
            <h4>{item.description}</h4>
          </section>
        )
      })}
      <br />
    </div>
  )
```

}

Comment: This solution isn't quite correct because you can potentially lose state if you get multiple clicks in before this.state updates. Instead, you should do all of the work inside a callback:
onClicked(number) {
  this.setState((state) => {
    let clicked = Object.assign([], this.state.clicked);
    ....
    return clicked;
  });
}

Comment: @Taras using your new function I get the error `index.js:87 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this3.state.clicked.includes is not a function`.

Comment: You need to create empty array in `constructor` like `this.state = {clicked: []}`.

Answer (score 0):

`state.pages` need to keep track of the individual click states, rather than an instance-wide clicked state

your onClick handler should accept an index, clone `state.pages` and splice your new page state where the outdated one used to be

you can also add `data-index` to your element, then check `onClick (e) { e.currentTarget.dataset.index }` to know which page needs to toggle clickstate

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow does a particularly poor job of code in comments, so here's the implementation of onClicked from @Taras Danylyuk using the callback version of setState to avoid timing issues:

```
onClicked(number) {
  this.setState((oldState) => {
    let clicked = Object.assign([], this.state.clicked);
    let index = clicked.indexOf(number);
    if(index !== -1) {
      clicked.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      clicked.push(number);
    }
    return { clicked };
  });
}
```

The reason you need this is because you are modifying your new state based on the old state. React doesn't guarantee your state is synchronously updated, and so you need to use a callback function to make that guarantee.